# Convert comma separated string to int list and validate

Tags: c#, linq

I've converting comma separated string to List.
Problem while a list contain empty value or invalid value, how to skip invalid value?

```
List<int> list = model.Categories.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

string will be `"10,12,3.0,4,1k,5,0.0"`;

Comment: What is an invalid value for you? Do you have non-int values in your string (which are not empty or white spaces? for example just some random string?)

Comment: Yes, It'll be contain non int values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanna validate that only valid ints will reach the `Select` use `int.TryParse`:

```
int num;
var result = model.Categories.Split(',')
                  .Where(i => int.TryParse(i, out num))
                  .Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

If using C#7.0 then can just be:

```
var result = model.Categories.Split(',')
                  .Where(i => int.TryParse(i, out int num))
                  .Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

---

To not have to parse twice you can try something like this too:

```
Func<string, int?> ParseOrDefault = (input) => 
    int.TryParse(input, out int num) ? (int?)num : null;
var result = data.Split(',').Select(ParseOrDefault).Where(i => i != null).ToList();
```

Or better:

```
var result = data.Split(',')
                 .Select(i => int.TryParse(i, out int num) ? (int?)num : null)
                 .Where(i => i != null).ToList();
```

Comment: If you use CS6, you don't even need to define the int variable, you can just use `TryParse(i, out int num)` inline.

Comment: thank @GiladGreen, Can I use `Select(m => { int.TryParse(m, out int num); return num; })`

Comment: @GiladGreen: Actually it would return 0 if parsing failed. TryParse will always set the output parameter (as it is obviously required to) and it is documented to set it to 0 on parse fail. Obviously you don't want to use the value if it failed but your last version addresses this excellently.

Comment: @Chris - oh ops true. :) Still I'd not just `return num` as in Govind's comment because it does not represent the true answer. Thank for correcting me

Comment: @GiladGreen: Yup. As I said your last version of code is basically the corrected version of what Govind was trying to do.

Comment: @GiladGreen is last one not returning List<int>? I've got error while trying to get this

Comment: @GovindSamrow - true - it's returning `List<int?>` - add a `Select` to cast to `int` (after the Where removes all the nulls)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `TryParse` instead of `Parse`:

```
List<int> list = model
   .Categories
   .Split(',')
   .Select(item => {
      int value;
      bool parsed = int.TryParse(item, out value);

      return new {
        parsed = parsed,
        value = value;
      };
    })
   .Where(item => item.parsed)
   .Select(item => item.value)
   .ToList();
```